# In Rails how to exclude do an index position on an each_slice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of posts with the following numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].

In my ERB I have the following:

```
<% @post.each_slice(2) do |post, b| %>
 <% if post.number != 1 %>
  <%= post.number %>
  <%= image_tag post.post_image %>

  <%= b.number %>
  <%= image_tag b.post_image %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Basically I want rows of the following:

```
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8, 9]
[10]
```

When I use the code above I end up with:

```
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
```

I kind of understand why. I'm basically saying slice into two and then I'm saying "well get rid of 1" so that gets rid of 1 and 2. What's the simplest way to say each_slice starting at index 1?

Comment: Best practice is to name your arrays with a plural. I would change `@post` to `@posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get rid of the first element of an array to iterate over the rest (in a way you want), using `[]` operator:

```
<% @post[1..-1].each_slice(2) do |post, b| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

also, I guess you should check if the second post exists (in case your array is even, like in your example), like this:

```
<% if b %>
  <%= b.number %>
  <%= image_tag b.post_image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I feel like this would be the answer but the moment I add it I get undefined method on my second image (updated the code to show this).

Comment: @Jake yup, you now have to check if the second element of this slice exists. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this

```
<% @post.drop(1).each_slice(2) do |post, b| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

This will produce output like this.

```
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8, 9]
[10]
```